# is there a way to change the value of the field that im comparing to in the find() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to compare the date field with a dateRange.
here is my original code:

```
let results=Show.find({_MovieId: paramMovieId, date : {$in : dateRange}},{});
```

But I want to compare the date field with a small manipulation. something like this:

```
let results=Show.find({_MovieId: paramMovieId, moment(date).add(1,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD'): {$in : dateRange}},{});
```

i can't seem to run this code and it seem like an impossible task to do.

Somebody knows is there a way to change the value of the field that im comparing to in the find() function?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of what the `dateRange` list will have?

Comment: [ '2018-07-22',
  '2018-07-23',
  '2018-07-24',
  '2018-07-25',
  '2018-07-26',
  '2018-07-27',
  '2018-07-28',
  '2018-07-29' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)** operator, you can build query expressions that can allow you to manipulate the date field and compare that with some expression list.

In the following example, **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)** is be used with a [conditional statement](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#using-expr-with-conditional-statements) such as **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** to compare the transformed date field ([a day added](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#perform-addition-on-a-date)) with the dateRange array within a `find()` method

```
db.show.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$setIsSubset': [
            [ { '$dateToString': { 
                'format': '%Y-%m-%d',
                'date': { '$add': [ '$date', 24*60*60000 ] } 
            } } ], 
            dateRange
        ]
    }
})
```

---

With **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** you can specify another option called `timezone` which sets the timezone of the operation result e.g. for a local timezone in Harare, Zimbabwe

```
{ '$dateToString': {
    'date': '$date',
    'format': '%Y-%m-%d',
    'timezone': 'Africa/Harare'
} }
```

uses the [Olson Timezone Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) format as the timezone of the operation and

```
{ '$dateToString': {
    'date': '$date',
    'format': '%Y-%m-%d',
    'timezone': '+02'
} }
```

uses the [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) format for specifying the timezone.

Comment: i need moment because the dates are saved in utc timezone and i need to change them to localtimezone and then compare them

Comment: No need for moment, with [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) you can include an option `timezone` to specify the timezone of the operation result.

Comment: worked perfectly. you seems like a nodejs expert! can you please check if u know the answer to this questions as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466355/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-value-of-the-field-that-im-comparing-to-in-the-find?noredirect=1#comment89901890_51466355

Comment: @codingnighter2000 It's the same question as the one above

Comment: sorry. here is it :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458777/can-not-update-a-document-via-findbyid-and-save-with-promise

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using aggregation framework. To override existing field you need [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) stage where you can use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to add one day to current date object and [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to format your date. Try in Mongo shell:

```
db.show.save({_MovieId: 1, date: new Date()}) // inserts today


db.show.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            date: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: { $add: [ "$date", 1*24*60*60000 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _MovieId: 1, date: { $in : ["2018-07-23"]}
        }
    }
])
```